# Mathematica solving ODE

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve fourth order differential equation. But I am not getting desired result.

I have a function

```
v[x_] := Exp[r x] { P*Sin[r x] + Q *Cos [r x]} + Exp[-r x] {R * Sin[r x] + S * Cos[r x]}
```

what I want is value of constants P, Q, R, S in function v using some given condition

I tried using formula:

```
Solve[{v'[0] == 0, v'''[0] == (2 F r^4)/k, v''[L/2] == 0, v'''[L/2] == 0}, P,Q,R,S]
```

But I am getting an error
Options expected (instead of S) beyond position 4

Comment: Change ,P,Q,R,S] to ,{P,Q,R,S}] and you should find your result. If you look at the documentation for Solve you can see that this is demonstrated. After you get your solution you might try using Simplify on that to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Bill it worked.